# Responsive horizontal layout using vh and vw units only

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, horizontal-scrolling

I'm using the jQuery script from the accepted answer in the following question to make a horizontal layout responsive to browser height changes:

[Resize images in a horizontal layout as the browser height changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078668/resize-images-in-a-horizontal-layout-as-the-browser-height-changes)

My question is, can the same be achieved with only CSS code using the vh and vw units?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To make sure I get you right: *You want a horizontally scrollable list of images that shrink/grow with the browser window (and want to use `vh`/`vw` for it).* Right?

You can insert the images as css `background-image`s rather than as `<img>` and use `background-size: contain` to resize them (with a `vh`-dependent `height` on the container):

```css
ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50vh;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

li:nth-of-type(1) { background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/80/120); }
li:nth-of-type(2) { background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/80/90);  }
li:nth-of-type(3) { background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/80/70);  }
li:nth-of-type(4) { background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/80/160); }
li:nth-of-type(5) { background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/80/100); }
li:nth-of-type(6) { background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/80/60); }
li:nth-of-type(7) { background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/80/70); }
li:nth-of-type(8) { background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/80/90); }
li:nth-of-type(9) { background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/80/130); }
li:nth-of-type(10) { background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/80/110); }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

*Edit: keep in mind that `background-size: contain` is a [performance bottleneck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502454). But adding `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` is [suggested as a workaround](https://coderwall.com/p/j5udlw/improve-scroll-performance-of-chrome-when-using-background-size-cover) for this.*

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. Using `background-images` with `background-size: contain` instead of `img` tags is an idea I never thought of. I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: Did it work? (I never really used this because the html grows ugly... either you have myriads of css classes and `<li class="img-192345862">` and the likes or you use the style attribute like `<li style="background-image:url(...)">` which is ugly as well. Have you found a better approach?)

Comment: Yes, it did work, but like you said I don't know if it's the best solution for a dynamic site.